# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracaleDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

How to remove run time exception in java program. Like  this  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracaleDriver`

[image]

Comment: Oracle driver jar is not in your class path. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: You need to specify the Oracle JDBC driver library on the class path.

Answer (score -1):

**If you have seen ***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracaleDriver*** run time exception then first you have to set a path oracle database to jdbc **

> Follow these step to remove above error

1. Open the oracle database folder in C drive
   ==> oraclexe ==> app ==> oracle ==> product ==> 10.2.0 ==> server ==> jdbc ==> lib
2. copy all jar file from ***lib*** folder and then goto jdk folder
   ==> ProgramFiles ==> Java ==> jre 1.8.0-251 ==> lib ==> ext
3. All jar files paste it in ***ext*** folder.
4. Set a path of oracle database and jdk .
   ==> oraclexe ==> app ==> oracle ==> product ==> 10.2.0 ==> server ==> jdbc ==> lib
   copy above path and paste it on
   go to This Pc
   RightClick ==> Properties ==> Advance Setting ==> Environmental Variables ==> System Variables ==> Path ==> edit ==> New
   and then paste it
5. Setup path of jdk same as above like this
   ==> ProgramFiles ==> Java ==> jre 1.8.0-251 ==> lib ==> ext
   copy above path and paste it on
   go to This Pc
   RightClick ==> Properties ==> Advance Setting ==> Environmental Variables ==> System Variables ==> Path ==> edit ==> New
   And then problem is resolve.
   **If you any problem then goto my youtube Channel all the above problems are solved**
   link is
   [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GrHJVRZr70]

Comment: Libraries like a JDBC driver do not belong in `lib/ext` (and in recent Java versions, this doesn't even work anymore.